# access and open DisplayActionSheet from view model

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

i have a toolbar in my content page where there is one item called add , on clicking over add i want to open `DisplayActionSheet`

i have created `ContentPage` `Toolbar` in `xaml` and attached `ICommand` to it in view model. Now `DisplayActionSheet` is accessible only in View hence i am not sure how will i able to access it and render it from view model.

xaml file

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="" Icon="ic_add.png"    Order="Primary" Priority="0" Command="{Binding OnAddContactCommand}"/>
    <ToolbarItem Name="" Icon="ic_search.png" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding OnContactSearchCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

View model

```
public ICommand OnContactSearchCommand => new Command(OnContactSearch);
public ICommand OnAddContactCommand => new Command(OnAddContactSearch);
```

events

```
private async void OnAddContactSearch()
{   
   //var action = await DisplayActionSheet(AppResources.select_contact_source, AppResources.cancel, null, AppResources.manual, AppResources.phonebook);
}

private void OnContactSearch()
{
   Debug.WriteLine("OnContactSearch");
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Alessandro said `Application.Current.MainPage` works fine for action sheets and alerts as well. To hide view specific stuff from view model I created an `IMessageBoxService` which is injected into the view models' contructors that need it. Note that I am using the [Autofac IoC container](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). For Xamarin's DependencyService you have change the constructors and look up the service in code.

**IMessageBoxService.cs**

```cs
public interface IMessageBoxService
{
    void ShowAlert(string title, string message, Action onClosed = null);
    // ...
    Task<string> ShowActionSheet(string title, string cancel, string destruction, string[] buttons = null);
}
```

**MessageBoxService.cs**

```cs
public class MessageBoxService : IMessageBoxService
{
    private static Page CurrentMainPage { get { return Application.Current.MainPage; } }

    public async void ShowAlert(string title, string message, Action onClosed = null)
    {
        await CurrentMainPage.DisplayAlert(title, message, TextResources.ButtonOK);
        onClosed?.Invoke();
    }

    public async Task<string> ShowActionSheet(string title, string cancel, string destruction = null, string[] buttons = null)
    {
        var displayButtons = buttons ?? new string[] { };
        var action = await CurrentMainPage.DisplayActionSheet(title, cancel, destruction, displayButtons);
        return action;
    }
}
```

**AppSetup.cs**

```cs
    protected void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder cb)
    {
        // ...
        cb.RegisterType<MessageBoxService>().As<IMessageBoxService>().SingleInstance();
    }
```

**Usage**

```cs
public class EditProductViewModel : AddProductViewModel
{
    private IMessageBoxService _messageBoxService;

    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }

    public EditProductViewModel(IPageNavigator navigator, IMessenger messenger,
        IMessageBoxService messageBoxService, TagDataStore tagDataStore) : base(navigator, messenger, tagDataStore)
    {
        _messageBoxService = messageBoxService;
        DeleteCommand = new Command(DeleteItem);
    }
```

...

```cs
    private async void DeleteItem()
    {
        var action = await _messageBoxService.ShowActionSheet(TextResources.MenuTitleDeleteProduct,
            TextResources.ButtonCancel, TextResources.ButtonDelete);
        if (action == TextResources.ButtonDelete)
        { } // delete
```

If you are doing viewmodel first navigation (s. [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/navigation/#passing_parameters_during_navigation) or [Jonathan Yates' blog](https://xamarinforms.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/creating-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-6-view-model-first-navigation/)) you may chose to make this part of the Navigator service. It's a matter of taste

Answer (score 6):

try with

```
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet();
```

Comment: Is this the right way to access under mvvm guidelines ?

Comment: This do the work, otherwise I think you should use MessagingCenter. Send a Message From ViewModel to View and, in View, use DisplayActionSheet

Comment: Or define a ActionSheetDisplayService and inject it in your constructor. If you do vm first navigation, you can provide the interface methods in your PageNavigatorService alternatively

Comment: @Kay can you give us the example of this approach