# DisplayAlert from ViewModel not displaying

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to display DisplayAlert from the  View Model, however its simply doesn't display. Is there some other way how to display alert from the VM? The permission is true so that works.

```
 private async Task TakePicture()
        {
            await Permission();
            var imageSource = Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayActionSheet(AppResources.AlertNewPhoto, AppResources.AlertNewPhoto, AppResources.AlertGallery);
            if (imageSource.Result == AppResources.AlertNewPhoto)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your constructor of `ViewModel` like following code.

```
 public PersonsViewModel(ContentPage page){

  page.DisplayAlert("info","test","Ok");

}
```

In your Layout background code, you can use it following code.

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        PersonsViewModel personsViewModel;
        public MainPage()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

            personsViewModel =  new PersonsViewModel(this);
            this.BindingContext = personsViewModel;



        }
```

If you can use plugin, you can use `ACR.UserDialogs`. https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Hello Leon, sorry i havent seen you answer. I will let you know later if it works. Thank you

Comment: hi, i have used a different solution. Sorry......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172374/access-and-open-displayactionsheet-from-view-model#

Comment: Ok, both of them are worked, can you accept my answer or share your answer, then accept it, it will help others who have similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using events

```
public MainPageVewModel()
{
   Application.Current.MainPage.Loaded += LoadCards;
}

private async void LoadCards(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // your code on View Loaded
  await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("working alert", "alert", "ok");
}
```